# Get the sum of all values in mysql

Tags: mysql

Let's say I have the following table.

```
mysql> desc items;
+---------------+------------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field         | Type                   | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+---------------+------------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| item_value    | int(11)                | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| item_quantity | smallint(5)            | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+---------------+------------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

The current SQL statement is simple for items with quantity of 1.

```
select sum(item_value) as total_value from items where user_id = ?
```

If a row has more than 1 quantity, I would like to take that into account when I add up the values for all users. Would it be easier to keep track of the total amount per row (`item_quantity` * `item_value`) or can I do it within a SQL statement?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do the arithmetic in the `sum()` statement:

```
select sum(item_quantity * item_value) as total_value from items where user_id = ?
```